# JQuery prev() with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to dynamically prepopulate a modal form with data that exists in a table. Here is my existing code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <th>header2</th>
         ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='column1'>A</th>
    <th class='column2'>B</th>
         ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open_dialog').click(function(){
   $('#opName').val($(this).prev().prev().prev().text());
   $('#opPrefix').val($(this).prev().prev().text());
   $('#opDefaultErrorString').val($(this).prev().text());
       $('#formModal').modal('show');
       return false;
  });
...
```

so I have had to ridiculously call prev() over and over because for some reason when i try to directly go to the column I want by using prev('.column1').text() it gives "an empty string".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not `$(this).parent().children('.column1')` jumps up to the enclosing  `tr` and then back down to the column you want

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.column1')`

Comment: Yes, these all work. Thanks guys! The real answer to why I was messing this up is below in @SLaks answer

Comment: while this works, using `prev()` guarantees that the siblings is before the current element while `siblings()` does not. correct answer for the question is to use `prevAll()` as SLaks pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.prev()` can only return the immediately preceding element.

You want `.prevAll('.column1')`.

Comment: Probably with `.first()`.